# Is there a toString() version for TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Is there a version of JavaScript's `toString()` for TypeScript?

I have a lot of objects and I want to `console` print them. Some fields do not need to be printed as well.

How can I achieve this in TypeScript?

Comment: it's the same. typescript gets compiled to javascript and that code is what is run at runtime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No there isn't, however you can easily implement a property `toString` on your objects providing their "prettyfied" JSON representation:

```
toString = () => JSON.stringify(this, null, '  ');
```

Returning a selective JSON representation of the fields you need, can simply be achieved with `Object.assign`

```
 toString = () => JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, {f1: this.f1, f2: this.f2}), null, '  ');
```

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript you can just override the toString method that is always present because of the prototype object. In TypeScript you have multiple options if it comes to class methods:

```
public toString = () : string => {
}
```

or

```
public toString(): string {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `toString()` with no problems, but the problem can be in types, so notice:

1.

```
var x: number = 123;
x = x.toString(); // compile error
```

2.

```
var x: any = 123;
x = x.toString(); // no error
```

3.

```
var x = 123;
x = x.toString(); // no error
```